Two-way binding Devextreme Angular error ts2322
In my Angular component I have a string|undefined variable.
When I try use two-way binding in template, I get this error

ts2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

This is a part of the component code:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-medomailingdlg',
  templateUrl: './medomailingdlg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./medomailingdlg.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent
{ 
  text?: string
}

That is a html template
 <dx-popup>
<dx-text-box label="ttt"  
  stylingMode="field"
  labelMode="static"
  [(value)]="text">    
</dx-text-box>
</dx-popup>


Initializing the variable as an empty string and not making it nullable would probably be the most straight forward fix text: string = '' If making it nullable is a must then a custom getter/setter would probably be the best fix.
`
TestComponent { 
  private _text?: string;

  get text(): string {
    return this._text ?? '';
  }`enter code here`

  set text(value: string) {
    this._text = value;
  }
} 

